# OpenCV - Correct waitKey to play back video file

Tags: python, opencv

I have a video to be played in opencv, it's a 60fps video with length of 11 seconds.

This is my script to play back the video and the timer shown it takes 17 seconds to complete the playback instead of 11 seconds. I understand that execution of code will caused some delayed, but when i calculated manually with a timer from the player pop up until video finished, it really takes 17 seconds.

P/S: I `use waitKey(17)` because of the rules of `waitKey(1/fps)`

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('test-60fps.mp4')
start = time.time()
while (cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if (ret ==True):
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(17) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break
end = time.time()
print(end - start)
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Appreciate if anyone could clarify on this

Comment: To control time accurately, `cv2.waitKey()` is not enough, because reading and processing also cost time.

Comment: calculate the time taken by other lines of code and try to subtract it from waitkey in a way that each loop takes 17 milliseconds in total.

Comment: @Silencer I did manually measure the time taken to play the video from beginning the player pop-up until it's finished, time taken is 17 seconds which more than the actual video length, i dont think execution of code cost so much time. Maybe anything to do with the `cv2.waitKey()` ?

Comment: you can try to set it to 1, and calculate the time. That way you can have a better idea of how much time it take to read, decode, and display the image. By my calculations, it take in this case, 9 ms you may use 8 in the waitKey and probably get the correct time. Or you can calculate how much time passed between the previous waitKey (after it ) and before doing the next waitKey, then do 17 (ideal time) minus the time taken, probably something around 9 and waitKey that amount of time. This way you will be more accurate.Howevewr waitkey accepts only int, so you have to think about this inacuracy